# SimpleDateFormat wrong week of year for last week

Tags: java, date, java-7

I need to get week of year for a given date. Using SimpleDateFormat produces wrong results for the last week of the year.

Example:

This produces week 52 correctly:

```
SimpleDateFormat w = new SimpleDateFormat("w");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2021, 11, 25);
System.out.println("Week: ${w.format(c.getTime())}");
```

produces: `Week: 52`

But the next day is already considered as 1st week of next year?

```
SimpleDateFormat w = new SimpleDateFormat("w");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2021, 11, 26);
System.out.println("Week: ${w.format(c.getTime())}");
```

produces: `Week: 1`

**This only happens in Java 7 and not in Java 8 and above!**

Comment: How do you define "week of year"?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes the problem is that there are different interpretations, but for reporting purposes, I would think of something that starts on the 1st of Jan and count even incomplete weeks as whole weeks. So if 1st of Jan falls on Saturday, I would still count that Week1 and so on.. I would expect the last week of year to be 52 or 53. Something similar to what's returned by https://www.google.com/search?q=current+week+of+year

Comment: No, not interpretation… *definition*. There are multiple definitions of week of year. They are all legitimate. But you must be able to clearly state *your* definition, or you’ll be lost. For example, the ISO 8601 definition is: A week-based year has either 52 or 53 whole seven-day weeks that start on a Monday, and week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `Calendar`. It's obsolete, and, more to the point, **incredibly bad** API.

There's a list as long as my leg as to what's wrong with it. The specific one of about 200 things that is relevant here is that, boneheadedly, its month value is **0** indexed. So, '12, 3'? That's the 3rd of Undecimber, or whatever you'd like to call **the 13th month**. That, or the calendar doesn't do 13th month in which case it leniently just assumes you meant to say 3rd of jan 2022 . Either way, that's week 1.

So why is The 2nd of undecimber (or if you prefer, via rollover, 2nd jan 2022) "Week 52"?

[**Because it is**](https://www.google.com/search?q=week%20number%20january%202nd%202022).

Week numbering is weird, but they have to be. A week starts on monday (or sunday, for my silly standards loving USian brethren), and can't start on any other day. That means unless Jan 1st so happens to fall on a monday, there's going to be weirdness; either days in 2021 counting as being in 'week 1 of 2022', or days in 2022 counting as 'week 52 of 2021'. In fact, from time to time there'll have to be a week 53. After all, 52*7 is 364, but there are 365.2475 days in a year, so unless you just want to make some days poof out of existence, every so often a week 53 has to exist for it all to add up.

**Use `java.time` instead**.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 3);
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.ENGLISH);
int weekNumber = ld.get(wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
```

java.time does many things fantastically, and one of the things is does great is that it tends not to hide complex things. For example, 'when does a week start' is **just not answerable**, not unless you tell me where on the planet you're asking this question. Hence, 'which week is it' is *also* not actually an answerable question until you tell me exactly which week-counting system we're using, and there is no standard that is universally accepted enough. Hence, you *have to* go through the rigamarole of making a separate `WeekFields` instance to capture that info. We do it here based on locale.

Comment: This is such a great answer to a bad question (of course months are 0-based) that I don't want to delete my question.. I'll have to adjust it

Comment: I have adjusted the month and regardless of Calendar or not, it is a problem and I found the answer partially.. will post below..

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not specific to `Calendar` as this would also show Week 1 if ran on the 29th of December for example:

`System.out.println("Week: ${new SimpleDateFormat("w").format(new Date())}");`

But it is specific to Java 7. It was fixed in Java 8.

And I found the explanation for this here (as @rzwitserloot also explained):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between
> the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
> Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different
> calendar year values.
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
> MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard
> compatible setting), **then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997**,
> and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three
> days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is
> SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on
> January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week
> 53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

This is really interesting..